# How to access shadowed DXL variables/functions?

Tags: ibm-doors

I encountered an error in a script I was debugging because somebody had created a variable with a name matching a built-in function, rendering the function inaccessible. I got strange errors when I tried to use the function, like:

```
incorrect arguments for (-)
incorrect arguments for (by)
incorrect arguments for ([)
incorrect arguments for (=)
```

Example code:

```
int length
// ...
// ...
string substr
string str = "big long string with lots of text"
substr = str[0:length(str)-2]
```

Is there a way to access the original length() function in this situation? I was actually just trying to add debug output to the existing script, not trying to modify the script, when I encountered this error.

For now I have just renamed the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the case that you had no chance to modify the code, e.g. because it is encrypted you could do sth like

```
int length_original (string s) { return length s }
<<here is the code of your function>>
int length (string s)  {return length_original s }
```